# Is it efficient to use strlib functions instead of char comparisons?

Tags: c, string, embedded

I'm working with a project which intends to implement a communication between a microcontroller and GSM Module. Microcontroller sends the next AT Command to the GSM Module as soon as it receives the true response for the previous At command.

Sytnax of At Command Responses are like below sequence:

```
<CR><LF>RESPONSE<CR><LF>
```

So i wrote an algorithm that checks for the First and Last < LF > character and keeps the characters between them as a string. So i can keep the responses as a string.

Then i'm doing a simple comparison like below:
(Let's assume that the true response for firstcommand is "OK" and for the second command is "CONNECT".)
So:

```
switch(CommandNumber)
{
    case 0:
         if(strstr(gsm_string,"OK") != NULL)     
         {
             CommandNumber++;
             GSM_SENDMESSAGE("AT+QIFGCNT=0");
         }
         break;

    case 1:
         if(strstr(gsm_string,"CONNECT") != NULL)     
         {
             CommandNumber++;
             gsm_send_message_CRLF("AT+QIMODE=0");
         }
         .
         .
         .
}
```

This method works perfect. But i wanted to be sure for whether using strstr is okey or not. Because the second method is to compare the received characters one by one without any string function but it takes so long and messy to write it. Hundreds of 'else's and 'if's. First method is short and tidy.

Edit: Actually my question is simple but i didn't want to look like i didn't research for the algorithm. You can just answer this skipping the above parts:

Should i just use strlib or do i need to compare received characters one by one to be efficient.

Comment: Unless you are really searching for a sub string you should use `strcmp` rather than `strstr`. More efficient as the former can stop as soon as there is any character mismatch. Other than that the string functions should be fine for your purpose as you would essentially have to do the same anyway if you wrote it yourself.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel unless you have to. Do you have a good reason to *not* use standard library?

Comment: @kaylum Actually the received string can be different from "OK". It does not need to be the exact same string. It is enough containing "OK" inside of it. For example, i can not use strcmp if the response is "OK\r", right? Just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Is the substring being searched for always at the beginning of `gsm_string`? If so, `strncmp` should be more efficient than `strstr`, especially when the substring doesn't match, as the match can fail straight away instead of searching the whole string. E.g. `if(strcmp(gsm_string, "OK", 2) == 0) { /* matches "OK" */ }`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Hmm, actaully yes. It starts from the beginning of 'gsm_string'. But i'm concerned about wheter there can be a mistake while receiving it. Actually i know the length of common command responses. They have maximum length of 10-15 characters. So i guess strstr does not cause much problem. Does it?

Comment: @abdullahcinar strstr() works fine. You can use it, You're just communicating with a simple and slow gsm modem on its control channel, not processing several gigabytes data per second. it only causes you as much problems as you create yourself.

Comment: @nos Thank you nos and all of you. As you said, i have decided to continue with strstr(), as i'm not working with big data. It can maybe continue the process even if it finds the substring. But the module sends at most 10 characters more. So it's better to make sure that the actual goal is reached. Because i'm little concernet about the starting of the string, it can be not the exact same substring in some cases.